# Getting PDO function to also return the row count

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

SO I made a function to do my PDO queries for me so I don't have to keep typing it. Here is the function.

```
if (!function_exists('query_db_select') ) :

function query_db_select($query, $where){
$query_params = array(
':var' => $where
);
    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex){

    }
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($count == 1){
    return $stmt->fetch();
    }
    return $stmt->fetchAll();


    }
endif;
```

So if I use this function it looks like this

```
$query = query_db_select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = :var", $something);
```

The question is, after I use this function, how can I possible get the row count OUTSIDE of this function? I run the query using the function in another php page, but I want to also get the row count as well as the `fetch()`

Also want some suggestions on how to make this function better if you got any ideas.

Comment: you can't, since you're returning an array of results. that array is TOTALLY disconnected from the db connection/query stuff. if you want the row count, then return the statement handle instead, and do your fetchAll in the calling context. worst case, you could `count($query)`

Comment: @MarcB That did it! I simply just used `count($query)` , that's all I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you are returning is a multi-dimensional array of records. The way you can iterate through the array could change from query to query. One way to return both the row count and the result set would be as follows.

```
if (!function_exists('query_db_select') ) :

function query_db_select($query, $where){
$returnArray = array();
$query_params = array(
':var' => $where
);
    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex){

    }
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $returnArray['rowcount'] = $count;
    if ($count == 1){
    $returnArray['results'] = $stmt->fetch();
    return $returnArray;
    }
    $returnArray['results'] = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $returnArray;


    }
endif;
```

You can later access the number of rows using `$returnArray['rowCount'];/* Or whatever your variable is that gets assigned to the return value. */` outside the function call.

Comment: This worked as well. This is good to know too, considering I will have a bunch of these specific functions to do my queries and stay a little more organized.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
if (!function_exists('query_db_select') ) :

function query_db_select($query, $where){
$query_params = array(
':var' => $where
);
    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex){

    }
    $myArray = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return array("count" => count($myArray), "elements" => $myArray);


    }
endif;
```

I see no point in handling the result differently if there is a single element. It is the hotbed of problems.

Comment: I ran into the issue of a user page I am creating having different parts that call different things. Some would call one row, some call every row that was returned in a `foreach`. It was telling me either I use `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` depending on how many rows returned. Using the count in the function was the only way I knew how to fix it.

Comment: You already have the value of "count" in the result and you can work with elements[0] if count is 1. I would refactor the code using this part if I were you to make sure it will be easier to maintain in the future.